# How do I make the main method wait until my Swing timer completes execution?

Tags: java, swing

I'm presently working on a traffic control for a cross junction. I created a method that processes the countdown for 4 bulbs. The countdown is working fine. The name of the method is `start(int lane)` so I want something to place the method in a loop to run 10 times like:

```
while (counter<10){
    int x = getnextlane(); // first choose a lane to run its timer
    start(x); //start running the lane's timer countdown to 0 from 10
    //I want the main thread to wait till the start(x) completes before it goes to the next line
    system.out.println("lane "+x+" is running"); 
}
```

I found out that when I run the Gui, the countdown starts but before it gets to zero, the println statement completes before it. That is:

```
output:
lane 1 is running
lane 2 is running
lane 3 is running
lane 4 is running
lane 1 is running
lane 2 is running
lane 3 is running
lane 4 is running
lane 1 is running
lane 2 is running
```

I want to make sure that the timer completes before the main thread jumps to the next line.

Comment: Did you try thread [join](http://www.journaldev.com/1024/java-thread-join-example)?

Comment: @AbdullahKhan: Neither comment above is correct. Please see Mike's answer for a better and safer solution.

Comment: Also your question above mentions Swing Timer, but no where do you show Swing Timer code. Rather you show a while loop, that while appropriate in a linear console application, will not work well in an event-driven GUI environment such as Swing.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels As much as Mike's answer is much better than a quick comment, given the lack of details in the OP's question, I'm not so sure that `thread.join` is not applicable here. I can imagine a situation where a thread (let's call it master) is started from an event, then this thread spawns some other threads (the `getnextlane` call above), thus doing a join on the "master" thread so that when it is over the "master" thread can fire an event like "Done". Thus why my first request was for a MCVE.

Comment: @asettouf: I can assure you with absolute confidence (and years of experience) that in this situation the OP absolutely does not want to use `Thread.join`. You can disagree, but from my own personal experience, doing this, will make the code much more complex and bug prone since in creating his own non-SwingWorker thread, the OP now has to take pains to be sure to make all Swing calls on the EDT. This is all simplified greatly by properly using a Swing Timer and event notificaiton such as via a "bound" property via JavaBeans.

Comment: @asettouf: and if you're the one who up-voted Sanjay's answer, you do know that his calling `start()` on the Swing Timer from within his background thread threatens intermittent Swing threading exceptions since he's calling this off of the EDT. He would have to wrap that call in a Runnable and queue it onto the event queue to be safe, adding unnecessary complexity to his answer and code.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels As far as I am aware, we have no clue where this loop is called. It could be from virtually anywhere, so in my opinion both Mike's and Sanjay's answer are correct so far. And I'm not disagreeing with you at all (no experience of Swing GUI so far), all I'm saying is that I see a loop, threads are started there and the execution continues without waiting for the result. That is virtually all we know, and from the description we know it's linked to a GUI, but we have no way to know how, thus again, my emphasis on requiring a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: i really appreciate all your responses. i just saw the name of the thread that runs all  (AWT-EventQueue-0) i want to create four different timer countdown that solely alows one to completely countdown before another one can start. i placed this timers in a method i created; i.e start(int lane). i however run in a loop for 10 times just as traffic lights would continue. my problem now is that these timers do not show any dependency but but i want one at a time.

Answer (score 3):

A swing application is a GUI application.  GUI applications are event-driven.
The right way of doing this type of thing in an event-driven application is by using events.

So, you are supposed to start your timers and then `return` from your current method (which you described as "the main method") to swing, so that swing can continue processing events.

When a timer fires, you invoke some function which checks whatever you want to check, and if all the necessary conditions are met, you invoke another function which performs some job as a result of the fact that all these conditions have been met.

In a GUI application you never sit somewhere waiting for something to happen, because while you are doing that, your entire GUI is frozen.

Also, in theory you could start threads to do the job, but then you would need to be careful because most GUIs are not thread safe, and this includes swing, so you will not be able to invoke any GUI methods from other threads.

Comment: i really appreciate all your responses. i just saw the name of the thread that runs all (AWT-EventQueue-0) i want to create four different timer countdown that solely alows one to completely countdown before another one can start. i placed this timers in a method i created; i.e start(int lane). i however run in a loop for 10 times just as traffic lights would continue. my problem now is that these timers do not show any dependency but but i want one at a time

Answer (score 0):

You can use Thread, threads scheduling is controlled by thread scheduler.So, you cannot guarantee the order of execution of threads under normal circumstances. also, you can wait till first thread does not complete.

However, you can use join() to wait for a thread to complete its work.

in your case, you can put swing timer to Thread & do Join.

```
Thread t = new Thread(
             new Runnable() {
                 public void run () {
                     while (counter<10){
                       int x = getnextlane(); 
                       // start(x); 
                    system.out.println("lane "+x+" is running"); 
                  }
                 }
              }
);
t.start();
t.join();
```

Comment: Your answer does not work well with the Swing GUI library as the proper solution is not to use thread join but event notification as per Mike Naki's's correct answer.